# WPF Custom DatagridColumn Binding issue

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I am trying to define a new column template for a datagrid that I can reuse across my application, but when I try and use it, I get:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=CanLogin; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'DataGridBetterCheckBoxColumn' (HashCode=56040243); target property is
>   'isChecked' (type 'Object')

XAML for Column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Class="BACSFileGenerator.UserControls.DataGridBetterCheckBoxColumn"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BACSFileGenerator.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="ColumnRoot"
             >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isChecked, Source={x:Reference Name=ColumnRoot}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace BACSFileGenerator.UserControls
{

    public partial class DataGridBetterCheckBoxColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
    {

        public object isChecked
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(isCheckedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(isCheckedProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty isCheckedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("isChecked", typeof(object),
              typeof(DataGridBetterCheckBoxColumn), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public DataGridBetterCheckBoxColumn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I am then trying to use it like this:

```
<DataGrid Margin="0,0,0,10" ItemsSource="{Binding UserAccessGrid}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="User" Binding="{Binding User}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <uc:DataGridBetterCheckBoxColumn Header="Login" isChecked="{Binding CanLogin}"/>
                <uc:DataGridBetterCheckBoxColumn Header="Export Payments" isChecked="{Binding canExportPayments}"/>
                <uc:DataGridBetterCheckBoxColumn Header="Create File Layouts" isChecked="{Binding canCreateFileLayouts}"/>
                <uc:DataGridBetterCheckBoxColumn Header="Change User Access" isChecked="{Binding canChangeUserAccess}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Can anyone explain to me the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Lets say we have

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public bool CanBeUsed {get;set;}
   public List<Employee> Employees{get;set;}
}
```

Few points which might have confused you :

1. There will be only one `DataGridBetterCheckBoxColumn` instantiated for a property. Multiple records doesn't mean multiple column instance for a property. Instead multiple `DataGridCell` are created for every `DataGridColumn`.

   But

   `DataGridColumn` is not a `FrameworkElement` or a `Visual` so, it won't appear in the `VisualTree`, and since it is not `FrameworkElement` so it doesn't have a `DataContext` property. Without `DataContext` how your `Binding` will work ? Ask your self. Since this `Column` cant have its  `DataContext` set, so it must have either a `ElementName`, or a `Source` or a `RelativeSource` for its `Binding` to work.

   Now, we know that there will be only one instance of a `DataGridColumn`, so naturally its `Binding` should (made to) use the `DataContext` (collection property will be part of this) of `DataGrid`.

   Now, see your `Binding`, where is its `Source` / `RelativeSource` ? There isnt any. Now, will `RelativeSource` make any sense here ? As `DataGridColumn` does not appear in the `VisualTree`, so `RelativeSource` wont apply here. We are left with `Source` property. What we should set now for the `Source` ? Enter `DataContext Inheritance` .

   ***DataContext Inheritance***

   `DataContext` inheritance will only work for `FrameworkElement` connected via `VisualTree`. So, we need a mechanism with which we can bring down this `DataContext` to our `DataGridColumn`.
   Enter `Binding Proxy`.

   ```
   public class BindingProxy : Freezable
   {
       #region Overrides of Freezable

       protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
       {
            return new BindingProxy();
       }

       #endregion

       public object Data
       {
          get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
          set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
       }

       // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
       public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }
   ```

   If we declare an instance of this `BindingProxy` as a `Resource`, we can get our `Source`.

   ```
   <DataGrid Margin="0,52,0,10" ItemsSource="{Binding Records}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      <DataGrid.Resources>
        <uc:BindingProxy x:Key="FE" Data="{Binding}"/>
      </DataGrid.Resources>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgt" Header="User" Binding="{Binding User}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
         <uc:DataGridBetterCheckBoxColumn isChecked="{Binding Data.CanBeUsed, Source={StaticResource FE}}" Header="CanLogin"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
   ```

   Now, you will see that your nasty `Binding Error` is gone.
2. To make your `CheckBox` binding to work properly, you need to handle its `Loaded` event.

   ```
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <CheckBox Loaded="CheckBox_Loaded"/>
        </DataTemplate>      
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   ```

   Code :

   ```
     void CheckBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         Binding b = new Binding();
         b.Path = new PropertyPath("isChecked");
         b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
         b.Source = this;

         CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;

         BindingOperations.SetBinding(cb , CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, b);
     }
   ```

   But now, we have one logical problem here. All our `CheckBox` are now bounded to the `DataContext` property `CanBeUsed` which will remain same. You might be thinking that `CanBeUsed` should be a property of `Employee` which is `ItemsSource` and not `DataContext` of `DataGrid`. So, when you check / uncheck any `CheckBox`, all will respond same.

But, we want to bind our `isChecked` property to some property of `Employee` record which will remain diff for every `DataGridRow`. So, we need to now change our definition of `isChecked`, after which entire code will look like below :

```
public partial class DataGridBetterCheckBoxColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
{
    public BindingBase isChecked { get; set; }

    public DataGridBetterCheckBoxColumn()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void CheckBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {          
        CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(cb , CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, isChecked);
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
<uc:DataGridBetterCheckBoxColumn isChecked="{Binding CanLogin, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="CanLogin"/>
```

If I missed any point, do let me know.